# Prove the following symbolic argument

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\exists x(A(x) \land \lnot B(x))$

$\forall x(A(x) \rightarrow C(x))$

---

$\therefore \exists x(C(x) \land \lnot B(x))$

Not sure how to go about this? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use Existential Elimination and Universal Elimination to the same witness, obtaining two propositional formulae; a conjunction and a conditional.   Form an argument using those to obtain the required conjunction, then use Existential Introduction to discharge the witness and arrive at the required conclusion.

$\begin{array}{l:ll}1& \exists x~(A(x) \wedge \neg B(x)) & \text{Premise }1 \\ 2& \forall x~(A(x)\to C(x)) & \text{Premise }2 \\ \hdashline \quad 3 & {A(c)\wedge \neg B(c)} & \text{Existential Elimination from $1$ to a witness of }c \\ \quad 4 & {A(c)\to C(c)} & \text{Universal Elimination from $2$ to the same witness}  \\ \quad 5& \phantom{A(c)} & \phantom{\text{Conjunctive Elimination from }3} \\ \quad 6 & \phantom{C(c)} & \phantom{\text{Conditional Elimination (Modus Ponens) from }4,5} \\ \quad 7 & \phantom{\neg B(c)} & \phantom{\text{Conjunctive Elimination from }3} \\ \quad 8 & {C(c)\wedge \neg B(c)} & \phantom{\text{Conjunctive Introduction from }6, 7} \\ \hline 9 & \exists x~(C(x)\wedge \neg B(x)) & \text{Existental Introduction from }8\text{, discharging the witness}  \end{array}$

Comment: Hi. I am unsure how I would simplify A(c)∧¬B(c). Can that just go to A(c) with the justification of simplification?

Comment: Yes, @SuhailPrasathong , it is also called "conjunctive elimination ($\wedge\mathsf E$)".  $P\wedge Q\vdash P$